# Why doesn't h2-console default db name match the db name defined in application.properties file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am new to spring boot and taking a beginner course on udemy developing a  project.

Below is my application.properties file -

```
application.properties
#logging
logging.level.com.vega.springit=DEBUG

info.application.name=Springit
info.application.description=Reddit clone using spring boot 2
info.application.version=0.0.1

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

#datasource (default to testdb)
spring.datasource.name=springit
```

The default database on the h2-console is still testdb

[image: Default database]

And this is what I see on the console -

```
2020-11-29 01:19:29.315  INFO 28396 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:358023a0-911e-4064-b2ec-e7046556c517'
```

My questions are -

1. Why doesn't h2-console display the database name that is set in the app.properties file?
2. Why does the console say database available at 'jdbc:hs:mem:xxx'?
3. When I try to connect to testdb or springit (as set in the file), I get following error -

   Database "C:/Users/zankh/test" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help)

Also tried, connecting to 'jdbc:h2:mem:springit', but still get the same error.
I can connect to 'jdbc:hs:mem:xxx' but that's not how it works for the instructor in the course. What am I doing wrong here?

TIA

Comment: 1. because it doesn't know anything about your configured datasource (it doesn't know anything about spring). 2. because that is what is being started, 3. that db doesn't exists so why should it connect. The db that exists is printed on the console. If it works for the instructor you aren't following his instructions (i.e. different Spring Boot version, additional dependencies etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding spring.datasource.url to the app.properties file

```
application.properties
#logging
logging.level.com.vega.springit=DEBUG

info.application.name=Springit
info.application.description=Reddit clone using spring boot 2
info.application.version=0.0.1

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#h2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

#datasource (default to testdb)
spring.datasource.name=springit
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:springit
```